# How to find out if some code is compatible with a certain Android API level

Tags: java, android, static-analysis

Consider we have a Java library that we want to use in Android as a dependency. Is there a way to find out if that library is compatible with a certain API level?

In particular, I know that a library contains calls to API level 19 methods, but I am able to run it with Android emulator using API level 16. Apparently any issues appear once you hit a method that is not available at the specified API version. Which makes sense to me, but I was wondering if there would a way to make sure that the code does not contain any calls to methods that are not available at a certain API level?

Answer (score 2):

Android studio will inform you if you are using methods aimed at higher apis then you are building against, or the support libraries will allow you to use methods not available at the time the framework was released
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html

Comment: In your own code it will.  If you include a dependency on library Foo, and it has a function that has a level dependency I'm not sure at all it would catch that.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks, yes this is the problem. The library itself is a Java library and not an Android library. Maybe I could fork it and try to wrap it into an Android project. I have it as a dependency and Android Studio is not complaining.

Comment: @Robin: If the library is open source, creating a modified version that's an Android library, where you can set the `minSdkVersion`, is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: @Robin, apologies, I missed the fact it was an Java library, CommonsWare has the right answer here

Comment: No worries dave :), it was still a good hint. Thanks  @CommonsWare, then I might do this.